# jasmin gateway create and config smpp server

Tags: php, sms-gateway, smpp, jasmin, jasmin-sms

I have 2 Jasmin installed on 2 different server

then I have Jasmin 1 and Jasmin 2

I want to create smpp server on Jasmin 1,  then put Jasmin 1 smpp info in Jasmin 2 on the other server then when I send SMS with Jasmin 2 the SMS send to Jasmin 1 over smpp and monitoring incoming sms

I do it like this

https://docs.jasminsms.com/en/latest/apis/smpp-server/index.html

but I get an error : Unable to connect to host IP:2275

Answer (score 0):

You should connect to the port: 2775 , not 2275. unless you re-configured the port before you connect.